# Hotswap classes and resources of feature deployed to jboss fuse

Tags: eclipse, osgi, jbossfuse, karaf, fuseesb

I am developing "features" with JBOSS Tools 9 (Eclipse) to be deployed on a fuse 6.2 (with fabric)
At the moment the features are deployed via deploy scripts and fuse downloads the feature from maven repository (`profile-edit --repository mvn:...`). I am able to remote debut the feature (`"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5001,server=y,suspend=n"`).

The problem is if i change something i allways have to run `mvn install`. To see the changes taking effect.

Is there a way to use the Fuse Server integration (i already added the fuse installation to my Eclipse server view) to sync with my sources/resources like with webapp development.
(probably the deployment must be changed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on `dev:watch *` (I think the name of the command is) from the shell in JBoss Fuse, which turns on watching the maven repository for SNAPSHOT JARs being updated, and then automatic redeploy those in the JBoss Fuse server.

Then you can develop locally and build the code with `mvn install` to deploy to your local maven repository, which the `dev:watch` then triggers.

Mind I cannot 100% remember the command name if its dev:watch or something else with watch. Also the arguments to the command can maybe be to watch a specific name.

Comment: thanks - this at least saves the stop/start commands of container after "mvn install"